# C# returning tuple - like Python

Tags: c#, python, return, tuples

I'm new to OOP and C#. I have a strong Python background and I was wondering is there an equivalent in C# for this

```
#Python

def outputSmth():
    num1 = 3
    num2 = 3
    str1 = "Hi"

    return (num1, num2, str1)  #Returning a tuple that can later be accessed
                               # by index
```

If there is no direct equivalent, which I doubt there is, what is the most proper way to do it?

Here's my function :

```
//C#    
static tuple PrintUserCreationMnu()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("----  Create the user ----\n");
        Console.Write("User ID               : "); string usrID = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("First Name            : "); string f_Name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Last Name             : "); string l_Name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Expected leaving date : "); string l_Date = Console.ReadLine();

        return ; //Here I'd like to return all my inputted values
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply return a `string[]` or `List<string>`:

```
static string[] PrintUserCreationMnu()
{
       // ...
    return new[]{ usrID, f_Name, l_Name, l_Date};
}
```

But in general it would be better to create a custom type `User` with meaningful properties and return that. Then you can access them via property instead of by index:

```
static User PrintUserCreationMnu()
{
       // ...
    return new User{ UserId = usrID, FirstName = f_Name, LastName = l_Name, Date = l_Date};
}
```

Even better would be to use the correct types, `int` for an `Id` and `DateTime` for the date. You can use the `...TryParse` methods(f.e. `int.TryParse`) to ensure that the format is valid.

---

For the sake of completeness, yes, .NET has also [tuples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx). But i wouldn't use them often because it's not clear what `Item4` is. No one knows that before he looks at the source code. So it's not a good type to return from a method(even less if it's `public`). However, here it is:

```
static Tuple<string, string, string, string> PrintUserCreationMnu()
{
       // ...
    return Tuple.Create(usrID, f_Name, l_Name, l_Date);
}
```

Comment: My ID really needs to be a string as IDs are formatted like U001ABCD but yeah I think I will create a User class.

Comment: @Gaboik1: note that i've edited my answer to show C# tuples

Comment: "You could simply return a string[] or List<string>" - this will not cater for the numeric type in the OP's question without having to add conversions.

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft: sure, you have to parse the strings to the desired type. That's what i've suggested with the `User`-class and the "correct types"-hint. The .NET4 tuples already support different types, so you could also return `Tuple<string, string, string, DateTime>` if desired. But your C#7 tuples are better, unfortunately they don't exist now

Comment: Yep, living in a dream world. Check my answer for a dynamic option. Still messy tho.

Answer (score 0):

Tuples are coming in C# 7 (current is 6.0). So, unfortunately not yet.

I cant wait for them, especially when dealing with methods that return more that one parameter (without having to set up structures to deal with them).

For now you need to return something like a `List`, `Dictionary` or a `Tuple` type but you have to new them up and assemble them in a method call and the break then apart on receiving them from the call. Further, you are limited to a single type in most of these constructs so you would have to box in and out of something like object. A bit of a pain!

You can find more on C# 7.0 features [here](https://www.infoq.com/news/2015/04/CSharp-7-Tuples).

I think your best option is going to be a dynamic expando object. I am afraid it's the best I can do!

**Method:**

```
public object GetPerson()
{
    // Do some stuff
    dynamic person = new ExpandoObject();
    person.Name = "Bob";
    person.Surname = "Smith";
    person.DoB = new DateTime(1980, 10, 25);
    return person;
}
```

**Call:**

```
dynamic personResult = GetPerson();
string fullname = personResult.Name + " " + personResult.Surname;
DateTime dob = personResult.DoB;
```

Comment: Yes it's a pain. And thanks for the link! When is C# 7 set to come out?

Comment: My rough guess is 6-12 months. Here is a thread discussing related bits: http://www.strathweb.com/2016/03/enabling-c-7-features-in-visual-studio-15-preview/

Comment: Even better - here is a link to the Roadmap! https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/Language%20Feature%20Status.md

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft: tuples exist since .NET 4. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @TimSchmelter there is a subtle difference between the Tuples you are thinking of and the way they are implemented in Python, which is the behaviour C# 7 will cater for.

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft: didn't know but read the article, thanks for the info. Will be a useful feature

Comment: No problem @TimSchmelter. I think dynamic may be the most elegant option. Answer updated.

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft: how often you needed to use `dynamic` in production code? Don't suggest features that should be used very seldom to a C# beginner as the standard way to return multiple properties from a method. He knows at compile time what properties he wants to return. So what's the problem in creating a type that holds these properties? Compile-time type checking is crucial in developing

Comment: @TimSchmelter, the poster is experienced with Python... :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118627/discussion-between-tim-schmelter-and-murray-foxcroft).